# How can I create a second multisite network in a subdirectory?

Tags: customization, multisite, installation

I currently have two Wordpress installations. One is in the web root directory and is a multisite installation using subdirectories, not subdomains. The other is a test site, in a subdirectory of the web root directory, and is currently a single-site installation. I would like to convert the test site to a multisite installation without disturbing the existing multisite installation.

Since this is a test site meant for checking new or updated plugins and themes before installing on the main network, it can't share themes or plugins with the existing multisite installation. In other words, I can't use a multi network.

I'm happy to move the test site to a subdomain if that is needed to allow a second network; however, I don't want to disturb the main sites if I can avoid it. Is there a way to have two multisite installations on the same server?

Comment: In theory as long as none of the slugs of the higher-level MultiSite conflict with (match) the subdirectory you want to install the other MultiSite in, you can install the second in a subdirectory, but you may end up with some weird errors. It would be wise to set up your second MultiSite at a subdomain - that way you don't have to change anything in the first install, but you'll also ensure that the second install remains completely independent of the first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your subdirectory name to the `Banned names` in your `Network admin`.
Look to this screenshot.
[image]
Then you should convert your site to `Multisite`, see this codex [article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).